# How do I create one column based on the names of multiple other columns in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following data frame:

```
ID   Brick    Vinyl     Stone
1    Yes      No         No
2    No       Yes        No
3    No       No         Yes
4    Yes      Yes        No
5    No       No         No
```

How would I create a new column based on the names of these columns so that I ended up with the following?

```
ID   Brick    Vinyl     Stone    Type
1    Yes      No         No      Brick
2    No       Yes        No      Vinyl
3    No       No         Yes     Stone
4    Yes      Yes        No      Multiple
5    No       No         No      Other
```

Note that IDs 4 and 5 are either 'Yes' for multiple columns or are all 'No'. The response I have recorded in 'Type' for those two entries doesn't have to be 'Multiple' or 'Other' specifically - if there is a default way of recording the desired information that will work just as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
In [146]: s = df[['Brick', 'Vinyl', 'Stone']].eq('Yes')

In [147]: sm = s.sum(1)

In [148]: df['Type'] = np.where(sm.eq(0), 'Other', 
                                np.where(sm.eq(2), 'Multiple', s.idxmax(1)))

In [149]: df
Out[149]:
   ID Brick Vinyl Stone      Type
0   1   Yes    No    No     Brick
1   2    No   Yes    No     Vinyl
2   3    No    No   Yes     Stone
3   4   Yes   Yes    No  Multiple
4   5    No    No    No     Other
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's perfect! One question - can you clarify what '.idxmax(1)' does exactly? reading that line it seems like if it sums to 1, it prints the name of the column but I'm not sure how

Comment: From the [docs for `idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html): "_Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis_". The `1` refers to the `axis` parameter- in this case it means column-wise.